# Running haskell from c# with arguments and receiving output

Tags: c#, haskell, process

I am trying to run haskell code in C#, but generally speaking I wan't to be able to communicate with command line in c#. I am able to run commands like "runhaskell hask", but I am still unable to run commands like "runhaskell hask < text.txt" which despite working in command line, does not work for the method I am using.

This is the code I have come up with.

C#:

```
private void Om_Programmet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string current_directory = 
        System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string project_directory = 
        //current directory, but abbreviated it to fit into code block.
        Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(D...

        string program = project_directory+"\\text.txt";

        string haskell_program = project_directory+"\\hask";
        string text_file = project_directory+"\\text.txt";
        string arguments = haskell_program+ " < "+text_file;
        Debug.WriteLine(arguments);

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "runhaskell";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new 
        DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadOutput);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new 
        DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorOutput);

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();

    }
    private static void ErrorOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
        }
    }

    private static void ReadOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
    }
```

Haskell:

```hs
main :: IO()
main = do
    c <- getContents
    putStrLn c
```

This code gives back the error message "hGetContents: invalid argument".

It seems like there is an issue with `getContents` reading the text file, but it seems to me like everything should be okay.

Comment: Why can there not be stdin in both?

Comment: `< text.txt` is a *shell* redirect. `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false` means that that won't work (as far as I understand it).